# How do I set up a self referential relationship using postgresql and sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table of Users, and for some of these users I have information on their parents. I would like to build a table structure so that I can call User.mother and User.father and return their objects. It would also be nice to be able to have a User.children which can be referenced as well, but this is not essential.

I have tried the following table

```
class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

User.father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
User.father = relationship(User, foreign_keys=[User.father_id], remote_side=User.id)

User.mother_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
User.mother = relationship(User, foreign_keys=[User.mother_id], remote_side=User.id)
```

However when I try to insert data I get the error

```
Undefined Table: relation "user" does not exist
```

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword. You would have to double-quote it to use it as an identifier. I strongly recommend you find a different name, e.g. `user_account`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't realise. I've changed instances of User to Person and user to person.  I now get the same error but with 'relation "person" does not exist'.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Before coding using Python and whatever ORM you choose, you should test using the PostgreSQL CLI - in this case `psql` and see does your query work as expected. You would then be able to see problems before they get all the way though your framework - basically, it it works through `psql` (or whatever client you're using) then your problem is with your framework and/or programming language and your question belongs on StackOverflow.If it fails the `psql` test, then it belongs here - but I have a feeling this is not a database issue and therefore off-topic!

Comment: Have you created the tables (`Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`)?